# How to avoid user's own token in the XSRF_TOKEN in a spring application

Tags: spring-security, csrf

Our application is built on spring framework.

We have added the dependencies for xsrf and enabled csrf security in the securityconfig.java file means we have not added `http.csrf().disable();` line in the above file. And also  mentioned `http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());` in the same file.

Now when our application is being tested by security team.Using their tool they are changing both the XSRF_TOKEN in the cookie and xsrf-token in the header to some user's own token and still our application is giving proper response instead of throwing forbidden.

But if both the values are different we are getting forbidden error.

**Is there any option to restrict user's own token?.**

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: The restriction is implemented by the browser, it is call same site policy. The browser is only sending cookies to the site, which set the cookie. CSRF is a brwoser protection. If your security team is using `curl` or Postman, then there is no protection.